# Sketch 3 app with Adobe Typekit?

Tags: web-fonts, sketch-app, typekit

Is it possible to work with Adobe Typekit's webfonts directly into BohemianCoding Sketch 3 app? The same as in Adobe CC.

If it is, how can I enable it?

FYI: I already have a Typekit paid account.